# Square with equilateral triangle trig proof question

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: PQRS is a square with side lengths a, and PQT is an equilateral triangle]

PQRS is a square with side lengths a, and PQT is an equilateral triangle.

This is a two part question, the first part of which was to find length TR, which I got as $a\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$

The next part is to prove that $sin(15)=\frac 12 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$

I managed to do it in a really long and hideous way, finding the length TR (assuming that a = 1/2) and finding pretty much every possible angle and side, eventually realising that angle TRS is 15 degrees, and then doing some really messy trig and simplifying.

But I feel like there must be a shorter, nicer way. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: $\triangle TQR$ is isosceles.

Comment: Of course! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $TA\perp PQ$ and $TB\perp SR$

Since $\triangle PTQ$ equilateral, $TA=\dfrac{a\sqrt3}{2}$ then $TB=a-\dfrac{a\sqrt3}{2}$

$$TR^2=TB^2+BR^2=(a-\dfrac{a\sqrt3}{2})^2+(\frac{a}{2})^2$$

$$TR=a\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}$$

Now, since $QT=QR$ , $\angle QRT=75$ and $\angle TRB=15$

$$\sin15= \frac{a-\dfrac{a\sqrt3}{2}}{a\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}}{2}$$